# back and forward button for webview in android. how?

Tags: android, android-emulator, webview

I'm working on a `webview`. If I click anything in my `webview`, it redirects to another link by using `webviewclient` class.

Now I put a footer contains `back` and `forward` button,  to do the functionality which in ordinary browser.

I can work about to `back` and `forward` of `webview`. It works fine.

Now I want to set a buttons in the footer are initially should be not focused and it should work clickable and not clickable dynamically.

Comment: You keep deleting and re-adding the same question. Perhaps you ought to rewrite the question. There may be reasons why people are not answering your question. I, for one, have absolutely no idea what the last sentence means.

Comment: when the webview loads intially there is no forward(canGoForward()) or backward(canGoBack()) options, isn't it? then i want set those buttons should not focusable or clickable. thats all buddy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this problem using `canGoBack()` and `canGoforward()`, we can disable those buttons using `obj_name.setEnabled(false);`.

[Here's a good sample from Google's, worth looking at.](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html)

Answer (score 6):

If your layout like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<WebView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/backButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:enabled="false" 
    android:text="Back"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/forwardButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/previousButton"
    android:text="Forward"
    android:enabled="false" />
```

Now we can implement that like this...

```
private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.webview);

//Web View Initialization
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

//Button Initialization
final Button backButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.backButton);
final Button forwardButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.forwardButton);

//Back Button Action
backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

           // Going back if canGoBack true
           if(webView.canGoBack()){
               webView.goBack();
           }
    }
});
//Forward Button Action
forwardButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Go Forward if canGoForward is frue 

           if(webView.canGoForward()){
               webView.goForward();
           }
    }
});
webView.setWebViewClient( new WebViewClient() {



    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished( WebView view, String url ) {

        super.onPageFinished(webView, url );

        //Make Enable or Disable buttons
        backButton.setEnabled(view.canGoBack());
        forwardButton.setEnabled(view.canGoForward());

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError( WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl ) {

        super.onReceivedError( webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl );
        Toast.makeText( WebViewActivity.this, description, Toast.LENGTH_LONG );
    }
} );
webView.loadUrl("www.google.com");//Your url goes hare
```